# reading 10G file into memory on cloud

Tags: python, azure, memory

I'm working on Azure. I have a 10G file that I want to read into memory. All these are either tab delimited or .dat files with some delimiter.I have the flexibility to create a computing environment on the go for reading and processing these files. How do I figure out optimal settings so that i can read the file in <5minutes into memory (I'm using Python 3.x. I will be using Pandas and Scikit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you could put your 10G file in [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction).

From [Azure Blob storage limits document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits) , throughput for single blob is up to 60 MiB per second or up to 500 requests per second.

[image]

Then you could download the file from Azure Blob Storage and read it into memory.

```
10240M / 60M/s = 170.67s/60= 2.84 min
```

Surely, the above restrictions are only with an ideal situation.The actual situation is also affected by the network environment and other factors.

So, you could improve performance in two ways in order to meet your requirements for less than 5 minutes.

1.To divide a blob into several parts and download it in byte order.

You could use `Range` or `x-ms-range` in [Get Blob Request Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) to return only the bytes of the blob in the specified range.

For example, the 10G blob file is split into 100 requests, send 100 requests per unit time.Then download it into local file for subsequent processing. Please ensure bytes wrote with right location. But this requires the system to have 10G of memory space for its use.

[image]

2.Read into memory at the same time when downloading every capacity that satisfies the quota.

For example, a blob is divided into 100 requests, send 5 requests per unit time. Run 20 times in order. Per 5 requests is written to memory and the following 5 requests will be sent at the same time. In this way ,system just allocates approximately 500M of memory space.

In view of the network instability resulting in the requsts interrupt need to be rewritten in the request range of bytes, I suggest that you divide file into more parts.

Also, the Azure server may be a better choice because the local test may not reach the ideal state.

Hope it helps you.